# Added text file in eclipse but cannot find it

Tags: java, text-files

I have a java project in eclipse. I right clicked my package and used the option: "add -> new textfile" a textfile was created but I cannot see it in my package.

Where do I located the textfile I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used New->General->Untitled Text File (I'm using Luna) the file appears in the text editor but isn't saved to the filesystem until you explicitly save it, and then you are prompted for the location to save it to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file as File -> Save or File -> Save As to locate it in package / directory.

Answer (score 0):

right click on you package New>Other>General>Untitled Text File

Comment: how does your answer improve on the previously accepted answer?